# Final keyword benefits for vals and case classes

Tags: scala

I am using final keyword for case classes by default, also for vals if its inside class or trait.
It protects me from being overriden.

But are there any performance benefits ?

Answer (score 4):

A [constant value definition](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions) of the form

```
final val x = e
```

where `e` is a *constant* expression, has the performance benefit of inlining constant `e` in the generated code.

In practice best to measure with [sbt-jmh](https://github.com/ktoso/sbt-jmh) to see if it matters in your particular scenario.